# Download bugzilla eclipse plugin?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, bug-tracking, bugzilla, mylyn

I want to download Mylyn bugzilla eclipse plugin from an update site.

Can anyone tell me the update site, because most of the links I found were invalid, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason you aren't getting any answers is because it's available from the main update site:
http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo

Search for mylyn, under Collaboration.

Comment: will you are right, i was able to download it from the helios main update site, thanks.